# Check users country

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to figure out how I can check the users country, and then execute specific code based on the result of the users country that I define. Any ideas?

Comment: Does your code run as a program *on* the users computer?

Comment: Yes, I've compiled it with Py2Exe.

Comment: Are you assuming internet access on the part of the user? In that case, you could do an IP lookup and try to match the region

Comment: Yes, the user will be required to have internet access. I'm unsure about how I would go about that.

Comment: You can make a popup that asks the user to select their country from a fixed list.  Or have them input their phone number and parse out the calling code.

Comment: Good idea djechlin. However I'd rather no user-input be needed from the user for this task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

Get user's external ip using a service:

```
f = urllib.urlopen("http://www.canyouseeme.org/")
html_doc = f.read()
f.close()
m = re.search('(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)',html_doc)
ip = m.group(0)
```

then use http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pygeoip/ to figure out a users country

```
geoip = pygeoip.GeoIP("GeoIPCountry.dat", pygeoip.STANDARD)
result = geoip.record_by_addr(ip)
```

Comment: Thanks Francis, I'll look into it in more detail. However I have a question. Wouldn't it be more simple to use a domain such as http://whatismycountry.com/ and then find the string on the site and match it with a predefined string.

Comment: IP's are pretty easy to match w/ regular expressions. country names would be much harder to parse out of the other text on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're only asking for ideas, you could check the language and/or timezone environment variables. The problem is that neither of these is guaranteed to be accurate - it wouldn't be surprising to find a computer in the Philippines set for en_US in America/New York.

Comment: Yes, I've thought about this. It would seem more realistic to match the IP with the region as InspectorG4dget stated. I'm just unsure about how I can go about doing that.

Comment: Then you're most likely looking for the GeoIP module at this point. Unfortunately, I can't find a good online doc for it right now, though I can find plenty of "hey, look at the cool thing I did!" blog posts extolling it's virtues...

Comment: Thanks, John. I'll take a look at the module.